# WebRTC-creating multiple connections is one RTCPeerConnection enough?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

to create multiple connections on a server with clients I need to keep multiple RTCPeerConnection connections between clients or one RTCPeerConnection and Offer enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a single connection between 2 parties.

So if you have a single server and many users around it then you need to create a separate peer connection for each **server <-> user** pair, so you need to have many RTCPeerConnection objects at server side.

This is how actually [SFU (Selective Forwarding Unit)](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/) architecture for WebRTC works